# Explanation of the Gelfond Lifschitz reduct

Tags: logic, model-checking, answer-set-programming

Can someone explain with a hands on example how the Gelfond Lifschitz reduct works in order to check stable model semantics?

## edit

a simple example here - at least as far as I understand the thing. So far grounding is clear to me - but the the application of the reduct is not. My goal in the end is to check stable model semantics of a program `P` and a supplied model `M`

Let `i`, `j` be constant symbols and `X`, `Y` be variables. Consider

```
d(X,Y,Z) :- a(X), b(Y), c(Z).
c(X) :- a(X), not b(X).
a(i).
b(j).
```

Decide using the Gelfond-Lifschitz reduct whether the interpretation `I = {a(i), b(j), c(i), d(i, j, i)}`
is a stable model of `P`.
Then the grounding looks like:

```
a(i).
b(j).
c(i):- a(i), not b(i).
c(j):- a(j), not b(j).
d(i,i,i) :- a(i), b(i), c(i).
d(i,i,j) :- a(i), b(i), c(j).
d(i,j,j) :- a(i), b(j), c(j).
d(j,j,j) :- a(j), b(j), c(j).
d(j,j,i) :- a(j), b(j), c(i).
d(j,i,i) :- a(j), b(i), c(i).
d(j,i,j) :- a(j), b(i), c(j).
d(i,j,i) :- a(i), b(j), c(i).
```

Now I start to apply the reduct. To me only the simple bits are clear:

```
P = {a(i), b(i), ... unclear part}
```

What is lacking & unclear to me:
- removal of default negations
- removal of not applicable formulas

Answer (score 1):

Due to `b(j).`, `c(j):- a(j), not b(j).` is not applicable and needs to be removed.
As all negated literals are deleted, `c(i):- a(i), not b(i).` is converted to `c(i):- a(i).`
Therefore, as `I = {a(i), b(j), c(i), d(i, j, i)}` is minimal representation of the remaining `P`, it is also stable.